# How to "unpivot" a spreadsheet with multiple, nested dimensions using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've attached two Excel screenshots illustrating my problem. I have data in a spreadsheet organized like this (sort of pivot-y):

[image]

...and I want to transform it (unpivot) into a vertical format like this:

[image]

Please note that a simple transpose will **not** solve this. If you look closely at the Excel file (specifically the 'How I Want It' tab), you'll see there's actually a total of 5 dimensions I'm dealing with.

Any guidance on approaches? Really hoping this can be done with Pandas.. not so sure it can be.

Link to Excel file here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hZLQPukHcJwfwmkoPwOPPv5_JViwgL6v

Comment: It looks like you want a transpose?

Comment: can you share your sample file?

Comment: Essentially, yes but I need to transpose from multiple, nested dimensions here. The index is actually defined across multiple row/column attributes. Hence my problem.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I reopen answer because solution is a bit complicated, not transpose only.

Comment: @idiocrash - Maybe the main problem is convert excel to DataFrame with MultiIndex, if my solution does not work is possible share your sample excel file? gdocs, dropbox, wetransfer...

Comment: @jezrael For future reference, if a question is closed incorrectly, please attempt to search for the correct one and edit the list. I'm 90% sure there is a duplicate for this question, but you would rather answer it than have it closed...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - please check comment above...

Comment: @jezrael You're free to do what you want, but I have a word of advice... if a question is not in a state that writing an answer is guaranteed to solve the OP's problem (as you yourself admit you're not sure), then leave it closed! Or, at least, vote to close as "too broad"/"no mcve".

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - you know how it think - if excel is ideal, then my solution working nice, so answer was added. But if necessary convert unnamed `MultiIndex` values it is not possible without file...

Comment: Here's a link to the Excel: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hZLQPukHcJwfwmkoPwOPPv5_JViwgL6v

Comment: Hi all, I've updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for reshape data:

```
#create `MultiIndex` DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('HowItIs.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=[0])
#print (df)

#get names for new columns values
a, b = df.columns.names

d = {'level_2':'Category', 'Section Subheading':'Mesurement_Period_Week',
      'SECTION TITLE':'Mesurement_Period'}

fin_order = ['Section_Title','Section_Subheading','Category','Mesurement_Period',
            'Mesurement_Period_Week','Value']
df = (df.unstack()
        .reset_index(name='Value')
        .rename(columns=d)
        .sort_values(['Category','Mesurement_Period','Mesurement_Period_Week'])
        .assign(Section_Title = a, Section_Subheading=b)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        [fin_order]
        )
print (df.head())
   Section_Title  Section_Subheading Category    Mesurement_Period  \
0  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples   FY15 P03 Dec Count   
1  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples   FY15 P03 Dec Count   
2  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples   FY15 P03 Dec Count   
3  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples   FY15 P03 Dec Count   
4  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples  FY15 P03 Dec Weight   

  Mesurement_Period_Week  Value  
0                     W1     53  
1                     W2     53  
2                     W3     53  
3                     W4     53  
4                     W1   2120
```

Last if need increment each value in `Value` column per groups:

```
df['Value'] += df.groupby(['Category','Mesurement_Period']).cumcount()
print (df.head())
   Section_Title  Section_Subheading Category    Mesurement_Period  \
0  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples   FY15 P03 Dec Count   
1  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples   FY15 P03 Dec Count   
2  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples   FY15 P03 Dec Count   
3  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples   FY15 P03 Dec Count   
4  SECTION TITLE  Section Subheading   Apples  FY15 P03 Dec Weight   

  Mesurement_Period_Week  Value  
0                     W1     53  
1                     W2     54  
2                     W3     55  
3                     W4     56  
4                     W1   2120
```

Comment: I don't think this quite addresses the depth of the nesting in the Excel. There's actually 5 dimensions. Tricky.

Comment: I posted the same Excel doc as the screenshots show: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hZLQPukHcJwfwmkoPwOPPv5_JViwgL6v

Comment: Yes, real data follows the same structure as the example data.

Comment: Super, please five me some time.

Comment: Do you need increment 1 to each Value per group?

Comment: ...I just realized that my 'How I Want It' tab has incremented values (left over from dragging as a "series" in Excel), but that was due to me not paying attention late at night so the increment step was not needed. In any event, you solved my main problem and one extra one that I mistakenly introduced! Thank you so much!